# ValueError: Setting an array element with sequence

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am trying to make an np.array from my dataframe column which contains float arrays of different lengths
example of column:

```
[0.123123, 0.123123]
[1.123112]
[0.123123, 0.123123, 0.123123, 0.123123]
```

and i am getting `ValueError: Setting an array element with sequence`

i tried:

```
np.array(df['vector'].tolist())
np.array(df['vector'].squeeze())
np.array(df['vector'].tolist(), dtype=object)
```

and they all lead to `ValueError`

pandas version 0.23.4

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @James my expected output is cosine_similaritry between this np.array and other

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate all of nested elements in you data frame column to a single 1D array, you can use `np.hstack`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'vector': [
    [0.123123, 0.123123],
    [1.123112],
    [0.123123, 0.123123, 0.123123, 0.123123]
    ]}
)

np.hstack(df['vector'])
# returns:
array([0.123123, 0.123123, 1.123112, 0.123123, 0.123123, 0.123123, 0.123123])
```